# Redhat container on pure docker engine

Tags: redhat, docker

I'm trying to get a rhel container running on a simple docker host.  The docker host is rhel7, fully subscribed properly.  I wanted to use the pure docker engine packages instead of the ones that came with redhat, but unfortunately it seems that subscription management and usage is not available once I switched to the pure docker engine.  I can run the image without issue, but once I try to use yum, no luck:

```
# docker run --rm -it registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7 /bin/sh
sh-4.2# yum update
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Yum and subscription stuff works fine on the main host system.  Anyone know of a way to get a redhat container working (and able to pull packages) using the pure engine and host's credentials?

Thanks!

Al

Comment: Don't use the upstream Docker version if you can possibly avoid it. The RHEL version remains slightly behind to protect you from the bugs - sometimes severe ones - which are very common in the latest releases. 1.10 was delayed for several weeks for this reason; 1.12 will be delayed for much longer for the same reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "official" way to develop containers (or apps to be deployed in containers) on an RHEL7 box is using the [Container Development Kit](http://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/overview/).

> Red Hat Container Development Kit provides a pre-built Container Development Environment based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux to help you develop container-based (*sometimes called Docker*) applications quickly. The containers you build can be easily deployed on any Red Hat container host or platform, including: Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host, and our platform-as-a-service solution, OpenShift Enterprise 3.

Italics are mine.

A subscribed RHEL7 (even a Developer subscription) will transparently let you use the RHEL repositories available to your subscription from the containers.

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like you can get this to work by mounting /etc/pki/consumer and /etc/pki/entitlement inside the container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /etc/pki/consumer:/etc/pki/consumer:ro -v /etc/pki/entitlement:/etc/pki/entitlement:ro --privileged registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7 /bin/sh
```

Any other, more "official" ways to get this to work?